# Does a time trigger workflow rule based on a date, with a field update on that same date, still execute if the field update changes the date?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a time based workflow rule that fires when TriggerUpdate1 is True.  When it fires, two time dependent workflow actions are kicked off (they're part of the same rule, just two actions):

1. At 1 Hour AFTER Contact: NextProcessDate

   a. Field Update the NextProcessDate to two weeks later (TODAY()+14)

   b. Field Update: TriggerUpdate1 = FALSE
2. At 2 Hours AFTER Contact: NextProcessDate

   a. Field Update: TriggerUpdate2 = TRUE

(As you might have figured out, I have a second workflow rule that swaps the ones and twos above, so I have an automated date updating process)

My two questions are:

A.  Will #2 execute?  I've changed TriggerUpdate to equal FALSE in #1.  On the one hand, I read in the FAQs that the the workflow rule will be in the queue and it should still execute (because workflow rules get re-evaluated before executing), on the other hand, not sure what "in the queue means" because #1 will have executed, does that mean #2 is shut down or still executed?

B.  Will #2 execute because in #1 I've changed the NextProcessDate to 2 weeks later.  Does NextProcessDate remain the same for the purposes of executing #2  or will the rule wait until 2 weeks later and then execute.

Comment: StartingAgain - why not mark your answer as the solution ? would help the rest of the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, turns out the answer is Yes to both A and B.  They both executed in my tests...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the criteria for the workflow rule.

1. If Rule 2 is set to fire only IF TriggerUpdate1 is TRUE, then the time based workflow for Rule 2 will be canceled when TriggerUpdate1 is set to false by the First rule.

You can check the status of the time based queue by clicking setup -> Monitor -> Time Based workflows

Comment: Rule 2 doesn't exist.  Both #1 and #2 are sub activities (i.e., time dependent workflow actions) under one rule.  If there was a rule 2, agreed that would be the behavior.  Does that change your answer at all or the same?

Comment: If Rule 1 criteria is based on TriggerUpdate1 being true, then my answer still stands. The second time based workflow will be canceled when TriggerUpdate1 is set to false

Comment: got it, thanks. yeah Rule 1 criteria has a requirement that TriggerUpdate1 is true.  Working on testing it...